# How to tell when a background job is 'done'

Tags: bash, unix, parallel-processing, background-process

Let's say I run the following command:

```
$ find /mnt/folder1 > file2.csv & find /mnt/folder2 > file2.csv &
```

Is there a way to signal when these jobs are done? Or do I need to poll something like `$ jobs` or `$ ps aux` in order to infer when they're done? What's the suggested way to handle this?

Comment: It normally prints to the terminal once the job is done.

Comment: You could run `wait`... if that's what you mean.

Comment: @MarkSetchell could you show an example of how that'd be run?

Comment: You just start a bunch of parallel jobs in the background, then run `wait` and you don't get your prompt back till they are all finished. If you want something more sophisticated, just say what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Setchell's comment spelled out:

```
$ find /mnt/folder1 > file2.csv &
$ find /mnt/folder2 > file2.csv &
$ wait
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to catch your commands unless you have a robust entity. In your case, you can find a PID of the process like:

```
pgrep find
12542
```

it will find all process ids of current ***find*** jobs. If there are none, you can assume that the jobs are done.

Comment: You're probably better off running jobs -pas opposed to pgrep, to ensure that there are no find child processes spawned from other parent processes.